# Problemas de Paginación en DataList de Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

Buenas noches,

Estamos implementando un pagina en primefaces donde en un componente datalist se desea mostrar un contenido. En el atributo value del datalist, se llama a un método que devuelve la lista de temas. El problema es que al setear el atributo rows=1 del datalist, se muestra únicamente la primer pagina pero no las demás.

Alguna sugerencia de como resolver este problema?.

Les dejo el parte del código.

```
        <h:form id="content">

            <p:dataList id="paginacionTeorico" value="#{teoricoControlador.listaTeoricosIdTema}" var="teorico" widgetVar="teo" rows="1"  paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" 
                        rowsPerPageTemplate="2,4,6" type="none" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" >


                <p:column>
                    <p:panel header="#{teorico.titulo}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{teorico.contenido}"/>

                    </p:panel>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataList>

        </h:form>

    </div>
```

ManagedBean

```
public List<Teorico> getListaTeoricosIdTema() throws PersistenciaExcepcion {

    Map<String, String> parametro = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(parametro.get("idTema"));

    return listaTeoricosIdTema = fachada.listarTeoricosPorId(id);
}
```